# Проблема в переносе сайта django на хостинг

Tags: python, django, сервер, хостинг

При запуске django проекта на хостинге выходит такая ошибка:

```
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user8888/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user8888/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/user88888/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/home/user88888/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 84, in close_all
    for conn in self.all(initialized_only=True):
  File "/home/user88888/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 76, in all
    return [
  File "/home/user88888/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 73, in iter
    return iter(self.settings)
  File "/home/user888888/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in get
    res = instance.dict[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/user888888/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 45, in settings
    self._settings = self.configure_settings(self._settings)
  File "/home/user88888/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 148, in configure_settings
    databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
  File "/home/user8888/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings
    settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
  File "/home/user88888/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in getattr
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/user888888/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/user888888/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 190, in init
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/lib64/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.settings'
```

Я пытаюсь мигрировать сайт на другой хостинг,как я понял,я что-то где-то не подключил.
Узнал что wising.py надо настроить пути Python.Проблема в том что в  моем каталоге с проектом с названием venv (virtual) нету python от слова совсем,там есть все те файлы которые я устанавливал через requirements.в virtual когда вызываешь команду python -V выдает python 3.8.

Вопрос в том что мне надо сделать чтобы исправить ошибку? и что придется еще поменять при миграции)

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что у вас нет файла settings.py в папке (пакете) mysite. По поводу venv - эту папку не нужно вручную переносить. Почитайте про виртуальные окружения. Нужно создать новое виртуальное окружение на хостинге, и установить туда зависимости из requirements.txt. Сам python не должен быть в этой папке, максимум там будут ссылки или "переходные" exe файлы, вызывающие настоящий python.

Comment: Venv лежит не в корне сайта,' /home/a0814568/venv38 ' это норма? установил все туда из requirements.txt. Ошибка так и осталось... 

 File "/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/lib64/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.settings'  '

Comment: Ошибка осталась - значит файл settings.py так и не появился. Наличие виртуального окружения никак не это не влияет.